# Erro build flutter web

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao compilar um painel Flutter Web

```
PS C:\Users\guto1\Desktop\localdeliveryadmin_flutter> flutter build web
```

Building with sound null safety

> Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint
> script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:2:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart':
> Error reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'
> (O sistema nÃ£o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. ) export
> 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions; ^
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:6:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart':
> Error reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'
> (O sistema nÃ£o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. ) import
> 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' as internals;
> ^ lib/screens/DashboardScreen.dart:62:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'dismissible'.
> dismissible: true,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/elegant_notification-1.6.3/lib/elegant_notification.dart:142:3:
> Info: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> ElegantNotification.info({   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20:
> Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.   return
> internals.guardWebExceptions(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.
>
> Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...
> 101,6s Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web. PS
> C:\Users\guto1\Desktop\localdeliveryadmin_flutter> PS
> C:\Users\guto1\Desktop\localdeliveryadmin_flutter> flutter build web
>
> Building with sound null safety
>
> Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint
> script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:2:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart':
> Error reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'
> (O sistema nÃ£o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. ) export
> 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions; ^
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:6:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart':
> Error reading
> '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'
> (O sistema nÃ£o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. ) import
> 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' as internals;
> ^ lib/screens/DashboardScreen.dart:62:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'dismissible'.
> dismissible: true,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/elegant_notification-1.6.3/lib/elegant_notification.dart:142:3:
> Info: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> ElegantNotification.info({   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20:
> Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.   return
> internals.guardWebExceptions(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.
>
> Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...
> 35,4s Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.

Comment: Provavelmente seja a versão do package Firebase, tente usar uma versão mais atual caso seu SDK Flutter esteja mais atualizado ou mais antiga caso o contrário. E lembrese de verificar se é necessária alguma modificação direto no index.html da pasta web.

Answer (score -2):

Atualize suas dependencias do firebase, ou remova o numero da versão deles ex:
firebase_core: ^x.x.x
vc deixa assim.
firebase_core:

E assim por diante com as outras dependencias do firebase.
Da um flutter clean, depois flutter pub get.
Recomendo reiniciar seu pc tbm.
Eu tive um problema semelhante, eu só corrigi minhas dependencias, mas tive que reiniciar o pc para voltar a buildar meu código.